# Connect xcode to mysql through php

Tags: mysql, objective-c, xcode

I am using the following code to insert in mysql table from Xcode app via php,

```
-(void)insertDetails:(NSString *)userEmail loginType:(int)type{

login_email = userEmail;

NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/insertLoginDetails.php?userEmail=%@&login_type=%d",userEmail,type];

NSData *dataUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",strResult);
}
```

This uses the GET method, can anyone please tell me how to use the POST method for the above process.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [NSUrlconnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to call the webservice

1. Use requestWithURL:(NSURL *)theURL

If you need to specify a POST request with HTTP headers make use of NSMutableURLRequest with these methods

```
-(void)setHTTPMethod:(NSString *)method
-(void)setHTTPBody:(NSData *)data
-(void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tutorial avaiable about `NSURLConnection`. like [Fetching data with GET,POST methods by using NSURLConnection](http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/)

[Fetching data with GET,POST methods by using NSURLConnection](http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/)  have expalined how to fetch data from server synchronously and Asynchronously.